# Modelling a many-to-many relationship using Domain Driven Design

Tags: java, c#, oop, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to model a many-to-many relationship using domain driven design.

A scheme in my model has zero or more parent schemes and zero or mode child schemes. The relationship between a pair of schemes is described as follows:

ParentScheme, ChildScheme, RelationshipRule, RelationshipPriority

I was thinking of modelling this using the following Scheme entity:

```
public class Scheme 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string SchemeName {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Scheme> Parents {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Scheme> Children {get; set;}
}
```

The problem with the above entity is that it doesn't capture the RelationshipRule and RelationshipPriority values. So I was considering creating a separate entity named SchemeRelationship

```
public class SchemeRelationship 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public Scheme Scheme {get; set;}
    public Scheme ChildScheme {get; set;}
    public string RelationshipRule {get; set;}
    public int RelationshipPriority {get; set;}
}
```

And also changing my Scheme entity to refer to become:

```
public class Scheme 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string SchemeName {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<SchemeRelationship> Parents {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<SchemeRelationship> Children {get; set;}
}
```

The problem I have with this approach is that in my domain a scheme relationship isn't really an entity. It doesn't really make sense for it to have an id. Perhaps it would make more sense to model the relationship as a value object? The only reservation I have about making it a value object is that value objects are supposed to be immutable, yet in our domain the RelationshipPriority could change for a relationship. I'm new to domain-driven-design so any advice on how best to model this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If many to many relationship between Parents and Children schema then, the below design might be useful for your approach

```
class Schema
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SchemeName { get; set; }
    public string RelationshipRule { get; set; }
    public int RelationshipPriority { get; set; }
}

class ParentSchema : Schema
{
    public IEnumerable<ChildSchema> Children { get; set; }
}

class ChildSchema : Schema
{
    public IEnumerable<ParentSchema> Parents { get; set; }
}
```

--SJ